# How to import all cities in Django_cities_light

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to import the cities of USA and Canada in Django cities light, so I my settings.py file looks alike

```
 CITIES_LIGHT_TRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = ['en']
 CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_COUNTRIES = ['CA','USA']
 CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_CITY_TYPES = ['PPL', 'PPLA', 'PPLA2', 'PPLA3', 'PPLA4', 'PPLC', 'PPLF', 'PPLG', 'PPLL', 'PPLR', 'PPLS', 'STLMT',]
```

After this :

```
 python manage.py migrate cities_light  
 python manage.py manage cities_light
```

But after all this :

I just got the cities of Canada not USA

I again did the step but data still not dumps , Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you do look into cities data you would see that acronym for United States in it is US

```
 CITIES_LIGHT_INCLUDE_COUNTRIES = ['CA','US']
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify:

```
CITIES_LIGHT_CITY_SOURCES = ['http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities5000.zip']
```

The configuration parameter CITIES_LIGHT_CITY_SOURCES, comes with the default value
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/cities15000.zip that has cities with a population
over 15000, if you need to load cities with less population please use another source. For the list of available source please check here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt